# jQuery - find including self

Tags: javascript, jquery

This gives empty output, because console.log is never called. How can i force jQuery to find on all elements, even top level elements?

```
    $("<div attr></div><div></div>")
       .andSelf()
       .find('[attr]')
       .each(function (index, el) {console.log(el);});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use find to find the descendant elements with the said properties using `.find('[attr]')` then add back the root elements matching the filter using `.addBack('[attr]')`

```
$("<div attr></div><div></div>")
    .find('[attr]')
    .addBack('[attr]')
    .each(function (index, el) {
    console.log(el);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2hrZh/)

Comment: ty, but find must return nothing, i dont understand why this find must be there